# Does the Work Function have any effect on the Current of a Photoelectric Circuit?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I understand that varying the work function (while staying above the threshold energy) only effects the maximum kinetic energy of the photoelectrons, which in itself would not make a difference to the current in the circuit.
But does it also affect the number of photoelectrons released?

Answer (score 0):

In the photoelectric effect, an incident photon gives up its energy to an electron. I would assume that the angle between the direction of motion of the photon and that of the electron is predicted by a probability function which does not change with time. That angle, and the energy, determine whether the electron can overcome the work function and break away from the surface. If you increase the work function, then a smaller fraction of the electrons will be within an angle that allows escape.